# Count number of chars excluding newlines

Tags: php, newline, strlen, chars

I'm using strlen() to count the number of chars in a text, but it even counts newline \n. Can i replace newlines is some way to make strlen() don't count them?

Comment: Considere adding code to your question ;) For your problem, you could copy your string to a temporary one, strip the newlines from it then count the number of char in this temporary string

Comment: `strlen(str_replace("\n", "", $str));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this first replace all `new line character` by `null`  and than count length.

```
echo strlen(str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", "\r"), '', $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "Testing \n testing";


$x = strlen(str_replace(array("\n","\r","\r\n"), "", $string)); //replace '\n \r' with nothing before counting the rest
```

Answer (score -4):

you can subtract one, like this:

```
$x = stlen(str);
$x--;
```

Comment: And what if there are X "\n"'s in the string

Comment: then check it with an if(strlen(str) == 1) ... or if(str == "\n") ...